# What is the definition of a bipolaron and a dipolaron?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, definition, quasiparticles

I wondered about the exact definition of a bipolaron?
In particular, if I have an oxygen vacancy in a metal oxide and the 2 excess electrons (when forming a neutral oxygen vacancy) localise on the 2 surrounding metal atoms, is this a bipolaron?
And does the term "dipolaron", for having two electrons (holes) localised at the same (metal) centre, exist?

Comment: Would [Chemistry SE](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com) page be a better place to ask this question?

Comment: Yes, maybe I can try. I think this question is on the borderline between both physics and chemistry.